# seekg doesn't go to beginning of file

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to make a random name generator. The problem is that in order to get the count of lines in the file, I have to loop through it.

So when I need to loop through it again in `getRandomName()` to get a name, it has already reached the end of the file

I tried solving the issue with `seekg(0, std::ios::beg)` but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
int getLineCount(std::fstream &names) {
  int count{};
  while (names) {
    std::string name;
    getline(names, name);
    ++count;
  };
  // last line is empty
  return count - 1;
}

std::string getRandomName(std::fstream &names, int lineCount) {
  int randomNum{getRandomNumber(1, lineCount)};
  std::string name;
  names.seekg(1, std::ios::beg); // here i try to go to the beginning but it doesnt work
  for (int i{0}; i < randomNum; ++i) {
    names >> name;
  };
  return name;
};

int main() {
  std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(nullptr)));
  std::rand();
  std::fstream names{"names.txt"};

  int lineCount{getLineCount(names)};
  std::cout << getRandomName(names, lineCount);
}
```

Comment: Reaching end of file sets the EOF-bit along with the fail bit, meaning your stream is in error state. You need to [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error before you can go on.

Comment: On the other hand you don't need to read the file twice at all – just count the lines while it's open, and when reaching appropriate number you have reached the line in question. If a read error occurs earlier (with EOF bit set) then your file simply didn't provide enough lines... If you need to look up often once then maybe buffering the lines in a `std::vector` instead might be better alternative.

Comment: Yet another possibility: In the 90's the GNU recommendations for simple helper programs was: when in doubt read the file into core memory and then work on the data.

Comment: shouldn't you seek to 0 instead of 1?

Comment: *seekg doesnt go to beginning of file* `names.seekg(1, std::ios::beg);` doesn't go to the beginning of the file.  It goes `1` character into the file.  Assuming the error bit isn't set.

Comment: @Aconcagua indeed,  reading in a vector would make a big difference.  Except if it's a very large corpus of very large strings in which case, OP could still save the position of the lines to get random access! If you post an answer I'll upvote ;-)

Comment: `Doesn't work` is not description of a problem!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a file stream considers reaching the end of the file as an error condition and sets the according bits, both the fail-bit and the EOF-bit. As long as this state persists, any further file operations fail. You can set the stream back to the normal operating state by [`clear`ing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error state, though – if you do so, then you'll be able to proceed as intended.

If need those lookups frequently then it might be worth to consider buffering the data lines within a `std::vector<std::string>` – unless if you have to handle extremely large data (thus provoking paging effects) this would be far more efficient. Even *with* paging effects, but with large enough disk space available you still get better for every lookup as you'd have to load at most one memory page back from disk.

If you need the lookup just once then you might get along without the `getLineCount` function entirely – select a random value from entire maximum range and just count the number of lines until you found the desired line – *or* the end of file got reached. If the latter happens, then recalculate the random index based upon the number of lines found and iterate of over the file *again*. The larger your file is, the greater is the chance that you only need to iterate once, and if you still need to do twice, nothing is lost anyway... Note, though, that this approach requires your random number generator generating equally distributed random numbers!

This would work for multiple calls as well, though the chance of a benefit get's smaller as with every further call the chance of reading beyond file size *at least once* increases.

Comment: I'm afraid that getLineCount() would be required even if the lookup is only done once,  because it needs to know the number of lines in the file first to calculate a random number in the right range, before accessing the line ;-)

Comment: @Christophe No, it wouldn't – you just use the unmodified result of `rand()` – if there are sufficient lines, you're fine, if not, then you re-calculate the index by the maximum of lines found before and read again. Sure, there's still the chance you need to read the file twice, but only in *some* cases while you might be lucky in others – the chance for the latter increasing with file size, so exactly when it gets more relevant.

Comment: Well, it all depends what OP expects from the randomness. If the distribution matters,  the two methods are statistically not equivalent and your approach would create a bias.  For example, if input file has more than RAND_MAX lines,  the trailing lines will never occur.  Conversely,  if it is a file smaller than RAND_MAX, but the random number obtained is larger than the number of lines, then, unless RAND_MAX is an exact multiple of the line count,  the first lines have more chances to be drawn than the last ones.

Comment: @Christophe No, the first lines don't have a greater chance – provided we can silently assume an equal distribution for the random numbers (if not, the approach indeed fails – added a note), as every line still gets the same chance. Note that if the random number is too large I *recalculate* the index based upon the maximum found! And yes, in *that* case we still iterate twice, but *only* then.

Comment: About `RAND_MAX`: Well, on commenting lost from view the fact that there's a separate `getRandomNumber` function... But that doesn't change anything (still equal distribution provided!): Simply replace `RAND_MAX` (didn't use in my answer anyway) with the maximum value getRandomNumber is expected to accept and we're back again, even if there are more lines than `RAND_MAX`. This new maximum still being too small is not covered by the question either so I don't consider this relevant...

Answer (score 1):

Your `getLineCount()` functions reads with [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) through the file until nothing can be read anymore.  When it arrives at the end, an [error state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is set, with `eofbit`.

All subsequent actions on the stream will fail, including `seekg(0, std::ios::beg);`, until you [`names.clear();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error state.

By the way, looping on `getline()` avoids `getline()` to fail in the loop body, and makes the -1 unnecessary. Another thing you could do is to make your function neutral for the read position of the file. It's optional bu would me more consistent with the name of your function which suggests that it just gets something, not that it consumes the stream to the end.

```
int getLineCount(std::fstream &names) {
    int count{};
    std::string name;
    auto old_pos = names.tellg();   // backup current position
    while (getline(names, name)) 
        ++count;
    names.clear();                  // reset eof error caused by loop
    names.seekg (old_pos, std::ios::beg);  // restore position        
    return count;
}
```

### Not related

Your random position might lead to inconsistencies, if names on a line can include whitespaces, because `>>` reads space separated strings and not full lines.  E.g.  if your file has two lines:

```
 Bjarne Stroustrup
 B.W.Kernighan
```

Your random read could return `Bjarne` or `Stroustrup` but never `B.W.Kernighan` because there are 2 lines but 3 space separated strings.  So better read the random line as you count them, using `getline()` again.

Comment: I'd recommend leaving the seeking of the beginning of the file within `getRandomName`, though, as that might possibly be called multiple times.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, I agree. `getRandom()` must do everything necessary to position itself, keeping in mind that it can be called several times, and not knowing what happens before it is called.  The backup/restore of the position suggested in `getLineCount()` is just meant to leave the stream as it is, as `get` strongly suggests that nothing is altered.  As said, it's optional, in case it's reused in more complex algorithms.  Alternatively the function could be renamed `countLinesToEnd()` which gives a hint that it goes to the end. But as soon as we're in names, it becomes quickly subjective ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should start from adding logs (I've also fixed minor issues, like inconsistent reading of data, `1` instead `0` and so on).

```cpp
#define LOG(x) std::cerr << __LINE__ << " " #x " = "<< x << '\n'

int getRandomNumber(int a, int b)
{
    static std::random_device rd; 
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distrib(a, b);

    return distrib(gen);
}

int getLineCount(std::istream &names) {
  int count{};
  std::string name;
  while (getline(names, name)) {
    ++count;
    LOG(count);
    LOG(names.tellg());
  };
  return count - name.empty();
}

std::string getRandomName(std::istream &names, int lineCount) {
  int randomNum{getRandomNumber(1, lineCount)};
  LOG(randomNum);
  std::string name;
  LOG(names.tellg());
  names.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  LOG(names.tellg());
  for (int i{0}; i < randomNum; ++i) {
    getline(names, name);
  };
  return name;
};

int main() {
  std::ifstream names{"names.txt"};
  LOG(names.tellg());

  int lineCount{getLineCount(names)};
  LOG(lineCount);
  std::cout << getRandomName(names, lineCount);
}
```

This produces this output https://wandbox.org/permlink/EPLHqMBg1s8Awe9F :

```
44 names.tellg() = 0
23 count = 1
24 names.tellg() = 13
23 count = 2
24 names.tellg() = 27
23 count = 3
24 names.tellg() = 40
23 count = 4
24 names.tellg() = 53
23 count = 5
24 names.tellg() = -1
47 lineCount = 5
31 randomNum = 4
33 names.tellg() = -1
35 names.tellg() = -1
```

`-1` indicates that stream is in error state.

And this is obvious you have read file to the end, so there was attempt to read beound file and error flag is set.

When error flag is set, stream is unusable until flag is cleared. So just adding `names.clear();` in proper place fixes issue: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Us6b3Jw3v6JFwlpX

Answer (score -1):

In your `getLineCount()` function use `while (names.peek() != EOF)` instead.

Comment: advice to use `while (names.peek() != EOF)` is worst possible advice and ignores what is actually an issue.

Comment: Additionally `peek` looks for a single character, meaning that you'd need to check and count the new-lines manually, too – and you'd need two operations for every character, one for peeking, another one for ignoring it.